# Another inequality about another sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence such that $a_0=1 , a_1=2 , a_{n+1}=a_n+\dfrac {a_{n-1}}{1+ (a_n-1)^2} , \forall n \ge1  $ , then is it true that $ 52 < a_{1371} < 65$ ?

Comment: Yes. Approx 54.18348. What is this about? I just wrote a one line Mathematica program and ran it. Are you looking for something else?

Comment: If your question is 'How would I show this by hand?', please say so. Otherwise one can just appeal to numerical methods.

Comment: We can get a quite tight asymptotics by just squaring the recurrence relation. We have that $a_n$ grows like $\sqrt{2n}$ plus a logarithmic term.

Answer (score 0):

We have:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}a_{n+1}^2 &=& a_{n}^2 + \frac{2a_n a_{n-1}}{1+(a_n-1)^2} + \left(\frac{a_{n-1}}{1+(a_n-1)^2}\right)^2\\&=&a_n^2+\frac{2a_n^2}{1+(a_n-1)^2}+ \left(\frac{a_{n-1}}{1+(a_n-1)^2}\right)^2-\frac{a_n a_{n-2}}{(1+(a_n-1)^2)(1+(a_{n-1}^2+1)}\end{eqnarray*} $$
hence, since $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is increasing, we have that for any $n$ big enough ($n\geq 8$):
$$\sqrt{2n}\leq a_n \leq \sqrt{2n}+\log n.\tag{1}$$
$(1)$ proves that $a_{1371}$ is between $52$ and $60$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate , how for $n \geq 8$ , the inequality $(1)$ follows ?

Comment: We have $a_{n+1}^2= a_n^2+2+E(n)$, where $E(n)$ is a small error term. By computing the first terms of the sequence, you can check that $\sqrt{2n}\leq a_n\leq \sqrt{2n}+\log n$ holds by induction for any $n\geq 8$.